# Clarification on halting predicate computability

Tags: computability, halting-problem

I am tackling the halting problem right now and its remarkable theorem. My book states $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ is true if $\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal P}$ is defined and conversely $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ is false if $\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal P}$ is undefined.

The purpose of the theorem, of course, is showing that $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ is a not computable predicate. I will report the extract of the proof given:

Suppose $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ were computable. Then we could construct the program $\mathcal P$:

$$[A]\;\;\;\;\;\text{IF HALT}(X,X)\text{ GOTO } A$$

It is quite clear that $\mathcal P$ has been constructed so that

\begin{equation}
\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal P}=
\begin{cases}
\text{undefined} \;\;\; \text{if HALT}(x,x) \\
0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{if ~HALT}(x,x)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I don't understand how $\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal P}$ is undefined if $\text{HALT}(x,x)$ is true, shouldn't $Y$ be equal to $0$ by default and moreover how could a non-terminating program <del>be defined</del> can have $0$ as output value. What am I missing here?

***Edit***: $\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal P}(x)$ is the value of the output variable $Y$ at the terminal snapshot.

Comment: What's $\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal{P}}$? As to how a non-terminating program could be defined, here is one in C: while (1) {}.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus added what is $\psi^{(1)}_{\mathcal P}(x)$. And I am sorry I meant to ask how come that a non-terminating program can have 0 as output value?

Comment: what book? (curious)

Comment: @usul: "Computability, Complexity, and Languages" by Davis, Sigal and Weyuker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's walk through the proof given by [Davis94].  I am familiar with this text and have it in front of me.  The HALT predicate is defined:

$$
HALT(x,y) \Longleftrightarrow \text{program number $y$ eventually halts on input $x$.}
$$

Given this defintion of HALT, don't worry about how such a program would be defined.  It is not important.  Just *assume* that HALT exists, that it works, and that this is what it does: It uses $y$ (a Gödel number -- see Section 8 of Ch. 3) which represents a particular program, and $x$, an input to that program, and tells us if that program halts when it is run with that input.  It can do this for *any* program, with *any* input.

Now, let's define a new program called $P$:

$$
[A]~\text{IF}~HALT(X,X)~\text{GOTO A}
$$

Look at how we are using HALT here: we are asking "Does program X halt when given an input of X (itself)?"  And if it does halt, we loop infinitely -- creating a program that does not terminate -- a program that does not halt.  In other words:

$$
\psi_P^{(1)}(x) =
\begin{cases}
\text{undefined} & \text{if} & ~~~~HALT(x,x) \\
0 & \text{if} & \sim HALT(x,x)
\end{cases}
$$

Let's pause and answer your first question about $\psi_P^{(m)}$ being undefined: this is part of the definition given in Section 4 of Chapter 2: $\psi_P^{(m)}(r_1,...,r_m)$ is undefined if $P$ never terminates.  And our program never terminates when $HALT(x,x)$ is true because we have written it that way, it loops infinitely.  As to your second question about the default output of 0: this happens when the program $P$ ***does*** terminate.

Now let the Gödel number of our new program $P$ be $y_0$.  This means that

$$
HALT(x,y_0) \Longleftrightarrow ~ \sim HALT(x,x).
$$

(we are taking the left side from the definition of HALT and the right side from our program $P$).  Since this is true for *any* input $x$ we could also write:

$$
HALT(y_0,y_0) \Longleftrightarrow ~ \sim HALT(y_0,y_0),
$$

which is clearly a contradiction; HALT cannot exist.

Answer (score 4):

In the definitions in this question the relationship between the program and its inputs and the arguments of the $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ predicate is missing.

Suppose $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ is true if the program encoded by the number $x$ terminates on an input $y$.

Now assuming $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ is computable, define a program $\mathcal{P}$ as in the question. Note that if $\text{HALT}(x,y)$ is false, the program does nothing and the tape holds its default value of 0.

The input-output relation defined by the program $\mathcal{P}$ is

$$
\psi^{(1)}_\mathcal{P} (x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} undefined,&\textrm{if }\text{HALT}(x,x)  \\ 0, &\textrm{if not } \text{HALT}(x,x)\end{array}\right.
$$

Now let $x_{\mathcal{P}} = \mathop{\textrm{code}}(\mathcal{P})$ be the number that encodes the program defined above. Then  $HALT(x_{\mathcal{P}},x_{\mathcal{P}})$ might be either true or false.

Consider the first case when $\text{HALT}(x_{\mathcal{P}},x_{\mathcal{P}})$ is true. Then $\mathcal{P}$ terminates on x_{\mathcal{P}, therefore $\psi^{(1)}_\mathcal{P} (x_{\mathcal{P}}) = 0$, but according to the definition of $\mathcal{P}$ it should be undefined. Thererfore $\text{HALT}(x_{\mathcal{P}},x_{\mathcal{P}})$ cannot be true.

Similarly $\text{HALT}(x_{\mathcal{P}},x_{\mathcal{P}})$ cannot be false (you can check).

This is a contradiction to our initial assumption of the computability of $\text{HALT}(x,y)$.